# Authenticating Page Requests without cookies

Tags: http, authentication, cookies

This question is to verify that I am understanding something correctly. I am currently devising a web based application that would involve multiple pages (think, different SPAs under the same domain), and I would like to have one and only one authentication point.

My question, then, is the following: while on an SPA it is possible to store authentication tokens on local/session storage, to my knowledge the only way of authenticating a **page request** (a link to another page, not an asynchronous request) is to do so with a Cookie, regardless of the authentication method I'm using (Basic, OAuth, JWT, etc).

Am I correct? Is this the only method available?

Answer (score 2):

It's a broad question, but I would say that generally the answer is probably 'no'. There's a number of things you can do.

When you mention 'one authentication point', I'm go assume you mean 'single sign-on'. There's lots of system that enable single-sign on.

On a broad level, this is how that might work:

1. User goes to one of your applications.
2. User automatically gets redirected to an authentication page (on a central domain).
3. User logs in, and the login information gets stored in (for example) LocalStorage. This allow this information to be stored.
4. Single sign-on system redirects the user back to the original application, and embeds a single-use token in the url.
5. Original application uses the token to obtain multiple-use tokens.

This is a very common flow in OAuth2.

Comment: To see if I'm understanding correctly, there is a single use token in a GET (page) request, that I assume is visible on the address bar, that gets captured by a script and used to get more sensitive credentials asynchronously?

Comment: @PabloBarríaUrenda yes, that's a common scenario. I'd highly suggest to read the OAuth2 specification as most of your problems have been solved by folks who spent a long time thinking about the matter. Plus you get the benefit of borrowing a lot of existing OAuth2 code for clients and servers.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot. Due to my misunderstanding of how bounties work, I failed to give you the 50 points, so I'll give you 100 instead in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I know several options:

- cookies (doesn't require explanation)
- Basic HTTP authentification

  It is secure to use Basic Authentication in conjunction with HTTPS. 
  Authentification header is repeated between requests, so credentials are entered once. 
  The only problem is ugly Browser popup requesting credentials
- adding token/signature to each link by javascript or by server-side HTML processing

  E.g. using jQuery, NOTE that code is simplified

  ```
  $(document.body).click('a', e => {
      var $a = $(e.target).closest('a');
      if($a.length) {
          e.preventDefault();
          document.location = $a.attr('href') + '&token=' + secretToken;
      }
  })
  ```

Please find [good article explaining available authentification methods here](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/)